# Perl: Why should "last" not be used to exit a grep or map?

Tags: perl

The [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) say the following about `last`:

> `last` cannot be used to exit a block that returns a value such as `eval {}`, `sub {}`, or `do {}`, and should not be used to exit a grep() or map() operation.

Why *should* it be avoided in a *grep()* or *map()*?  I'm especially curious about *map* since it is an alternative to the foreach construct.  The docs seem to insist on not doing something without describing the consequences.

Comment: map transforms a list into another list, so each map invocation should return an element

Comment: I get the error `Can't "last" outside a loop block` trying to exit `map` with `last` using perl v5.14.1 in WinXP.

Comment: @TLP: And that's been the case since at least Perl v5.10.1. I'm guessing that this "should not" language is a holdover from some earlier version of Perl when it must have caused some weird behavior.

Comment: @TLP, Are you saying the docs should say not to use `last` in an `if`? Cause you get the same error if you put `last` in an `if`.

Comment: @ikegami Not quite sure what you are getting at. I am saying you *cannot* use last in `map` (v5.14). Nor `if`, by the looks of it.

Comment: @TLP, I use `last` to exit `if` statments all the time. `while (1) { x(); if (y()) { last; } x(); }`. You can do the same with `map`. But the docs say not to. Why?

Comment: @ikegami Ah, I see what you mean. That was rather subtly phrased in the docs, if that's what they meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, realise that `grep` and `map` are transparent to `next`, `last` and `redo`, just like `if` is.

```
$ perl -e'
   print "A";
   for (8,9) {
      print "B";
      print map { print "C"; next; print "D"; $_ } 1,2,3;
      print "E";
   }
   print "F\n";
'
ABCBCF
```

But the docs doesn't say `last` *cannot* be used to exit `map`, it says it *shouldn't* used. It's not clear what that means.

- Don't use them thinking they will affect `map` and `grep`?
- Don't use them that way because your reader might think they affect `map` and `grep`?
- Don't use them that way because it can leave Perl in a wonky state?
- Don't use them that way because the behaviour might change in the future?

I don't know.

I don't think it's #3 because I don't know of any bad side-effects of using `next`, `last` and `redo` to leave a `map` or `grep` callback.

The funny thing, leaving `map` and `grep` using a loop construct doesn't even warn even though leaving a sub in the same fashion does.

```
$ perl -wE'while (1) { map { last; } 1; }'

$ perl -wE'while (1) { sub { last; }->(); }'
Exiting subroutine via last at -e line 1.
```

Comment: I am sure the intention is that `last` (and `next`) shouldn't be used to exit the implicit loop in `map` or `grep` because it actually exits a *containing block*. Note in particular that while a `last` at file level is illegal, `print "A"; print map { print "B"; last; print "C";} 1,2,3; print "Z";` prints just `AB` and so exits the entire program. The bottom line is that `map` provides a *mapping* from one list to another and **isn't**, as the OP said, an alternative to `foreach`.

Comment: @Borodin, Re "because it actually exits a containing block", is one of the possible *interpretations* I mentioned. It is not what the docs docs actually *say*, and you offer absolutely no evidence to back your claim that is must surely be the correct interpretation. Re "Note in particular", then why doesn't the documentation state not to use `last` to exit an `if`'s "then" block? It also exits a "containing block". You are rebutting my claim that the intent is not obvious by simply stating it is obvious. I am unimpressed. What was the point of your comment?

Comment: you must work on your aggression and oversensitivity. What I said was that I am sure of the intention of the documentation. Yes it was one of your alternatives. I didn't comment on whether the meaning of the documentation was obvious. I wasn't disagreeing with you at all. Please calm down.

Comment: @Borodin, What aggression? I calmly and logically explained why your comment contributed absolutely nothing, yet you're continuing to spew uncorroborated statements. Why do you claim the document means "cannot be used" when it says "should not be used"? How do you know how `map` is intended to be used?

Answer (score 8):

`map` is meant for *mapping* one list to another. It certainly **isn't** an alternative to `foreach`. I have seen too often things like

```
map { print "$_\n" } @data;
```

which commits the sin of using `map` for its side-effects and throwing away the resulting list. You wouldn't consider using

```
my $x = 99;
sqrt(my $y = $x * $x);
print $y;
```

and you would get a warning. For the same reason you shoudn't use `map` when you mean `for`.

For a practical reason, consider

```
print "A";
print map { print "B"; last; print "C";} 1,2,3;
print "Z";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
AB
```

so in this case the `last` exits the entire program. In general, using `last` or `next` inside a `map` or `grep` block exits the *containing* block, if there is one, otherwise the entire program. This is something to be avoided, hence *"`last` ... should not be used to exit a grep() or map() operation"*.

Comment: I meant an alternative foreach list generator, like how the *[docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)* say `%hash = map { foo($_) => $_ } @array;` is an alternative for `%hash=(); foreach (@array) { $hash{foo($_)} = $_; }`

Comment: There is no resulting "string" to throw away when you use `map` in void context, so your first argument is fatally flawed.

Comment: Your second argument is equally flawed. People do `func(my $y=EXPR)` all the time: `chomp( my $x = <> );` `utf8::decode( my $decoded = $encoded );` Both of those even have return values, which is more than one can say for `map` in void context!

Comment: @ikegami: I thought you knew better than this. `map` builds and returns a list of scalar values which is discarded in void context. I don't understand your point that *there is no resulting "string" to throw away*. And yes, it is valid to call a function that has side-effects in void context, but my example used `sqrt` which, like the use of `map`, calculates a value which is just discarded just for the effect of evaluating its parameter.

Comment: @ikegami: ah, perhaps you are referring to `map` being optimized now so that it doesn't build a mapped list if it is called in void context? But I'm still unsure why you think it's valid to use it in that way when the intention is a `for` loop (where `next` and `last` make sense and are valid). `grep` would suffice in the same circumstance, and I think it's clear that that would be a misuse. Is this a hangover from the Linux habit where we have to *concatenate* a file to the terminal? It is certainly responsible for lumbering us with the meaningless `grep` in Perl.

Comment: @Borodin, Your argument seems to be: A foreach loop is all you need, so `map` isn't intended to be used as a loop construct. That's an invalid argument (The conclusion doesn't follow from the argument), and I don't agree with the conclusion. What makes you think `map` should or shouldn't be used that way? I don't use it that way, but that doesn't mean it's wrong to use it that way. Someone people actually prefer putting the body before the list. And what does that have to do with the OP's question!?

Comment: @ikegami: I can only assume that you are deliberately missing the point and trolling for the sake of it. Your comments condone any Perl construct that works, so you would also allow `grep` and `sort` in void contexts, given that the internals behaved according to context? The `for` modifier also puts the list at the end, so I cannot see that `map` even has that advantage. Calling me a liar is rude and divisive: the first sentence in `perldoc -f map` says the same thing and you should take issue there as well. Write what you will - I will have no further in your obnoxious aggravation.

Comment: Re "Your comments condone any Perl construct that works", which comment do you think does that? Re "The for modifier also puts the list at the end", are you saying that `for` modifier shouldn't be used? `map` is far more useful than `for` modifier. Re "Calling me a liar is rude and divisive", I didn't call you a liar, I call your statment is a lie. Easy to prove it's wrong: `sqrt(qw( a b c )); map { say } qw( d e f );` Re "the first sentence in perldoc -f map says the same thing", Not mine. Mine says "Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting $_ to each element) and

Comment: ...returns the list value composed of the results of each such evaluation." Note how it performs a function (execute the block for every arg) after the argument list has been evaluated? It does that in void context too.

Comment: For some reason, I'm amused by this argument.  Better than PM-chatterbox :)  @Borodin: one thing that I have to remark on is the: "*meaningless `grep` in Perl*".  I find `grep` to be one of the best ways to remove *undef* elements from an array and in support of Ikegami's argument, Perl is all about TIMTOWTDI, so `map` as a for loop is viable.

Comment: @vol7ron: happy to keep you entertained! My point about `grep` wasn't that it is useless but that it is a misnomer. `grep` clearly isn't English and the word comes from *global regular expression print* which isn't what Perl's `grep` does at all. I'm just grateful we weren't lumbered with `cat` instead of `print`. Regarding `map` I would ask you the same thing: does TMTOWTDI mean that anything that does the job is fine? Would you be as happy using `grep` rather than `map`?

Comment: @Borodin: I wouldn't say that *anything* that does the job is fine, but `map` is special because its list iteration is similar to a `foreach`.  So imagine using `map` to [operate on]/construct a list, but to stop processing when the value meets some condition.  I was surprised to see that you should not use `last` in this case and was curious as to why.

Comment: The confusion comes from thinking of `map` as a loop in the first place. That may be how it is implemented internally, but it is there to perform a *mapping* from one list to another. The block is essentially a function to be applied to each member of the source to derive the corresponding member of the target. Functions (subroutines) don't have `last` statements.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, there is a decent amount of functionality overlap between `for/foreach`, `grep`, and `map`.  However, just because you *can* potentially use them all to solve the same problem, doesn't mean that they're all the best tool for that particular job (*see: using a screwdriver to pound a nail*).

- `grep`: Its purpose is to filter a list **and return the resulting subset**.
- `map`: Its purpose is to modify a list **and return the resulting modified list**.
- `for/foreach`: Its purpose is to iterate through a list and do *something*.

Now, you can accomplish every use of `grep` and `map` with `for/foreach`.  `grep` and `map` are basically syntactic sugar for specific uses of list processing (`for/foreach`) that are particularly common and useful.  By design, by convention, and by best practices, they trade certain things for increased convenience and clarity.

One of those things, is that `grep` and `map` are intended to return a value.  Using them in void context is discouraged, and considered to violate idiomatic Perl.  If you aren't returning a value, use `for/foreach`.  If you are returning a value, then `last` interrupts that process.

If you are following best practices for Perl, your use of `grep` and `map` will always be returning a value, which means that using `last` should be avoided.

Comment: +1. I'm not sure Perl has any official *best practices*, but I believe Damian Conway does :)  Most of his points are generally accepted in most programming languages.  Though, be careful.  He has inserted some personal preference points without conveying that it is personal preference.

Comment: Perl may not have an **official** best practices, but this isn't just a best practices from Damian Conway's book.  You'll see the same recommendation in the perldocs (quoted by Original Poster), in the 4th Edition of "[Programming Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do)", and in "[Effective Perl Programming](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/), 2nd Edition".  All considered, I'd say that makes it about as close as Perl gets to official best practices. ;-)

Comment: I never responded, but you'll find that all those guys are contributors to Perl CORE or work together on projects w/ each other.  They are all respected members of the Perl community and have had influence on the same unofficial list of *Best* Practices.  Just realize that they all are published by O'Reilly and just because one or two agree, does not necessarily make them *best*.  If you look elsewhere, you'll find that some of their so-called practices cause bugs. Still, it's best to get away from TMTOWTDI and use a popular style and convention. --- Also, wanted to note that I was the OP.

Comment: Agreed; I don't think there is any "best practice" for perl that doesn't have at least one acceptable "exception" case.  You never know when you might run into a case where violating a generally accepted best practice makes sense.  In this case, however, I do consider the above to be a valid best practice.  I agree with it myself, and not just because respected perl developers have pushed it as such.

Comment: Perl  has `for` abbreviations,  in terms of looking concise as map looks  ` for(@a) {print("$_","\n");} for my $i (@a){ print("$i","\n"); } `